# Connecting to Access 2010 with LabVIEW 2012

Tags: database, ms-access, labview

If LabVIEW and Access 2007 are installed on the same machine, the provider "Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider" (found under Tools->Create Data Link) can be used to create a connection to the Access database. On a machine with Access 2010 this provider is not listed (understandable as Accesss 2010 is part of MS Office V14, not V12) but no obviously suitable provider appears to be listed in its place.
How do I create a connection in LabVIEW 2012 to an Access 2010 database please?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions from ni.com "Can I Use LabVIEW to Open an Access Database Without Using SQL Functions?"  : http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/F763AA1D7CD3C83D862568E8007C51CD

Answer (score 1):

According to the NI Knowledge Base README file for the LabVIEW 2012 Database Connectivity Toolkit, you should be using the Microsoft Jet 4.0 (or later) OLE DB Provider

http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/4C95363F9DC59E1586257A13000F35F6#dbclient